# Regex troubleshooting with very specific pattern on newlines

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to manipulate a string in PHP to accomplish the following:

Example Input:

```
"""
line1\n
\n
line2\n
\n
\n
\n
line3\n
\n
\n
\n
\n
line4\n
\n
line5
"""
```

Desired Output:

```
"""
line1\n
line2\n
\n
line3\n
\n
line4\n
line5
"""
```

So far to achieve this in my javascript I have: `text.split('\n\n').join('\n')` and on the the PHP side I'm using this expression: `preg_replace('~(\R{2})\R+~', '$1', $text)`.

Those two methods do the job, but this process seems very funky and since regex is not my thing at all I would like to know if **there is a better way to do this?** Im sure there is :)

Comment: I do not get it, do you replace two consecutive "\n" with one ?

Comment: @MaxMuster Yes two consecutive "\n" with one and after that if there are more replace all those with another one

Comment: Try `preg_replace('~(\R{2})\R+|(\R){2}~', '$1$2', $text)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that is precisely it. Thanks. Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Different way.*

Try `(\R?\R)\R+` replace `$1` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMeUkl/1)

Features:

- Single, un-quantified capture to be written back
- No alternation
- Uses complete captured line break(s) for write back
- Most efficient way for what it does, 114 steps on user sample

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
preg_replace('~(\R{2})\R+|(\R){2}~', '$1$2', $text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IQ9Je8/1)

**Details**

- `(\R{2})\R+` - two line break sequences captured in Group 1 and then one or more line break sequences
- `|` - or
- `(\R){2}` - two line break sequences capturing the last one of them into Group 2.

The replacement is either the value of Group 1 or Group 2 (since one of them is always an empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Try find `(\r?\n)?(?:\r?\n){2,}` replace `$1\n`
optional match line break write back greater than 2.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gqj4o5/1)

or using \R   `(\R)?\R{2,}`

[demo2](https://regex101.com/r/3X8Xdn/1)

Comment: Looks like both ur solutions work, thank you so much. There was a person in the comments who gave the answer first so if he decides to write an answer I will give him priority otherwise I will mark this one as the correct one.

btw: demo2 links to no demo :)

Comment: Add the demo link for \R. Different regex's and philoposy. This is %30 more efficient, and it was 4 minutse after first comment. Doernt matter to me. My post says 3 hours ago and first comment all other comments say 2 hours ago. It really 4 minitues quicker though.